# Excel Filter formula with named ranges

Tags: excel

I'm looking to use the filter formula on a named range but there hasn't been a resource that has explicitly showed how to reference columns within a named range. I might add that the whole named range includes the headers due to the nature of the original data. It has 13 Columns.

The columns I want with their position is: "Injury Date" (6) and "INCURRED" (8)

```
=filter(Loss_Run,[Insert Chosen Columns Here])
```

This is the syntax I am trying to use but I cannot get it to work. I am not sure how to tell it to use the columns I want. Do I use the name of the columns or the number either way is fine to me.

I am trying to filter by a specfic value of a row and that is where the main hiccup is.

I got

```
=FILTER(Loss_Run,(Loss_Columns="Injury Date")+(Loss_Columns="INCURRED"))
```

to work.
BUT,

I want to first filter the first column, "ULGTACCT Code" (1) by a value (that is in cell A2 for our purposes). It is not allowing me to filter by the first column with or with out the other columns

What I have found says:

```
=FILTER(Loss_Run,(ULGTACCT Code=$A$2),"")
```

should work but I get `#Name?` error.

Answer (score 0):

To answer about calling a column within a table with name ranges and the FILTER function is things are much smoother if you specify columns as `=FILTER(TableName[ColumnName],include"argument")` within brackets "[ ]", this means that your table will need to be named to make this easier. That's how you would call a specific column.

To the other point of specifying the columns to `FILTER`, I have only found that to do this you write it as `=FILTER(TableName[@[ComlumnName1]:[ColumnName4]],include"argument")` and that should do it but I get an `#Value` error doing that.

I'm looking for any help as well with this so if this helps to bring you to a answer please share.

Comment: I ended up doing something else that changed that methodology.

Answer (score 0):

I was using

=FILTER(TableName, (TableName[Column]="SearchValue")

And I got all table rows back that were matching the criteria.